# Rails : how to display uploaded image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am new to ruby on rails,i have made basic code to upload the image and save ,my code is as below

```
    name = params['image'].original_filename
    directory = "public/"+params[:shop]
    #check directory exits or not
     if ! File.directory?(directory)
        Dir.mkdir directory
     end
    #  create the file path
    path = File.join(directory, name)
    # write the file
    File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(params['image'].read) }
```

and following is the code to display the uploaded image

```
<img src="/public/<%= @shop+"/"+@filename %>" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre" />
```

it gives the following image path on view
https://cf119e25.ngrok.io/public/fxdev1.myshopify.com/chasing_dreams_by_skyway.jpg
but the image is not displayed correctly.

is there anything wrong in code or need any library to  use?

Comment: Please check `gem paperclip`

Comment: For image uploading except `paperclip` you can also use gems such as `carrierwave`, `dragonfile` or `refile` - depending on your case

Comment: better carrierwave as paperclip is deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're reading the file from the public directory so

```
<img src="/public/<%= @shop+"/"+@filename %>" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre" />
```

should be

```
<img src="/<%= @shop+"/"+@filename %>" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre" />
```

so you're working URL is https://cf119e25.ngrok.io/fxdev1.myshopify.com/chasing_dreams_by_skyway.jpg

also its better if you use rails helper for image [image_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag) and more on asset pipeline [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)